# order by two value in WP_Query - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to order posts first by **date** and second by **views**

New update :

```
$trending_songs = new WP_Query(array(
                    'post_type' => 'songs',
                    'showposts' => $songs_count,
                    'cat'       => 'songs_cat-689',
                    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num', 
                    'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'orderby' => 'date',
                                'order' => 'DESC',
                            ),array(
                                'key'     => 'views',
                                'order' => 'DESC',
                            )

                    ),
));
```

the date is not working in the post (they just order by `views`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below code (this is just for sample you need to change according to your requirement)

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'words',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'word_count',
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'order' => DESC
            ,
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'title',
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'order' => DESC
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'word_type',
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'order' => DESC
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

Comment: array(
                'key'     => 'post_date',
                         'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                         'order' => 'DESC'
            ),

Comment: it's not currect ! can you help me  ? for date

Comment: Ok this is for custom field. You just need to `'orderby' => 'date'` try this may be helpful for you.